# Know slice number?

Tags: vtk

I have a DICOM series, with following origin, spacing and extent:

```
int nExtent[6];
double dSpacing[3];
double dOrigin[3];

m_pReader->GetOutputInformation(0)->Get(vtkStreamingDemandDrivenPipeline::WHOLE_EXTENT(), nExtent);
m_pReader->GetOutput()->GetSpacing(dSpacing);
m_pReader->GetOutput()->GetOrigin(dOrigin);
```

where m_pReader is vtkDICOMReader object ...

dOrigin is 0, 0, 0;

dSpacing id 0.447266, 0.447266, 3.998718;

nExtent is 0, 511, 0, 511, 0, 43;

the series is AXIAL. 
Now, if I slice the series through AXIAL plan, I could slice the series by 44 slices, like that:

```
double deltaY = 0.0;
delta += 1.0;

pReslice->Update();
double dSliceSpacing = pReslice->GetOutput()->GetSpacing()[2];
vtkMatrix4x4* pMatrix = pReslice->GetResliceAxes();
// move the dCenter dPoint that we are slicing through
double dPoint[4];
double dCenter[4];
dPoint[0] = 0.0;
dPoint[1] = 0.0;
dPoint[2] = dSliceSpacing * deltaY;
dPoint[3] = 1.0;
pMatrix->MultiplyPoint(dPoint, dCenter);
pMatrix->SetElement(0, 3, dCenter[0]);
pMatrix->SetElement(1, 3, dCenter[1]);
pMatrix->SetElement(2, 3, dCenter[2]);
```

Everything is allright ...

The problem: if I slice the series through CORONAL plan, the slices number are not 44 !! But how many ? How can I know the slice number if the plan is CORONAL or SAGITTAL ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Coronal and Sagittal slicing its more about position instead of slice index.

You need to calculate your min/max origin for each axis (x,y,z)

e.g.

```
myOriginMax.X = myOrigin.X + ((ImageDimension.SizeX - 1) * mySpacing.X);
```

You can compute your new origin in your slicing Event, where _positionDelta is your inc/dec value. (more or less pseudo code)

e.g.

```
double[] _origin = myImageReslice.GetResliceAxesOrigin();

if(_view == "SAGITTAL")
{
    _origin[0] = Math.Min(_origin[0] + _positionDelta * mySpacing.X, myOriginMax.X);
}
else if(_view == "CORONAL")
{
    _origin[1] = Math.Min(_origin[1] + _positionDelta * mySpacing.Y, myOriginMax.Y);
}
else //AXIAL
{
    _origin[2] = Math.Min(_origin[2] + _positionDelta * mySpacing.Z, myOriginMax.Z);
}

myImageReslice.SetReliceAxesOrigin(_origin[0], _origin[1], _origin[2]);

Render();
```

Comment: First of all, I haven't words to thank you enough for all your support ! :)

Comment: Secondly, I am starting to apply your pseudocode ... I will return with feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is another compute method ... in my case I have m_pReslice for axial plan, m_pReslice2 for coronal plan, and m_pReslice3 for sagittal plan ... I don't know if is the proper architecture, but applying your algorithm I arrive in the same place :)

```
m_pReslice->GetResliceAxesOrigin(dOrigin);

int nSizeX = nExtent[0] + nExtent[1];
int nSizeY = nExtent[2] + nExtent[3];
int nSizeZ = nExtent[4] + nExtent[5];

double dOriginMax[3];
dOriginMax[0] = dOrigin[0] + ((nSizeX - 1) * dSpacing[0]);
dOriginMax[1] = dOrigin[1] + ((nSizeY - 1) * dSpacing[1]);
dOriginMax[2] = dOrigin[2] + ((nSizeZ - 1) * dSpacing[2]);

dOrigin[0] = min(dOrigin[0] + 1.0 * dSpacing[0], dOriginMax[0]);
dOrigin[1] = min(dOrigin[1] + 1.0 * dSpacing[1], dOriginMax[1]);
dOrigin[2] = min(dOrigin[2] + 1.0 * dSpacing[2], dOriginMax[2]);

m_pReslice->SetResliceAxesOrigin(dOrigin);
```

this is the case for m_pReslice (axial plan) ... if I apply the algorithm for m_pReslice2 (coronal) and for m_pReslice3 (sagittal), I still don't know how may slices I have in coronal case (or sagittal) ...

Comment: What values do you get in you dOriginMax array?

Comment: Corresponding on the same DICOM series like in my first post, the values are: dOriginMax[0] = 228.10546875, dOriginMax[1] = 228.10546875, dOriginMax[2] = 167.94166992.

Comment: Also, I noticed something interesting: for all tested DICOM series, the size of the vtkDICOMReader on X plan and Y plan are 512 ... the size on Z plan are different by any DICOM series ...

Comment: Ok, if you compute the size with nExtent, then you don't have to subtract -1 of the value. Then the maximum origin is correct then. Of course the X,Y is 512, because your imagedimension is 512x512 pixels. The Z value depends basically on your count of slices. Check the values which you apply with dOrigin and if they increase or not. Make sure that you render afterwards.

Comment: I am thinking on something: if I know the size of the DIOMC object on X (sagittal) and Y (coronal), I should know how may slices I have on these directions, so, every slice index ... I will try it, and I'l return with feedback ... but I think that is happen only Monday ... I wish you a nice weekend ! :)

Comment: Johnny, you opened my eyes ... I think I get the trick ... now, everything is going right ... Kindly thank you !